# Why the element is remove from his parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/KvscH/6/ .

You can check through the `inspect element` that in the animation **SPAN** is throughout from **LI** But i didn't know why this happen & i want **SPAN** keep inside **LI**.

Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after this: **http://jsfiddle.net/TmNLE/**

```
var ticker = $('ul.ticker');
var tickerli = $('ul.ticker li');
ticker.children(':first').show();

$('.next').live ('click', function () {
    $('li:visible').fadeOut(function() {
       $(this).appendTo(ticker);
       ticker.children().first().show();
    });
});

$('.prev').live ('click', function () {
    $('li:visible').fadeOut(function() {
       ticker.find('li:last').insertBefore(ticker.find('li:first'));
       ticker.children().first().show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's working can you explain what's wrong in my code :)

Comment: **ticker.find(':visible').fadeOut(function() {** i found some different behaviour here and just tried some of the things there and got it as your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the javascript used.

For the 1st time Boo1 is visible because of the following line in javascript.

```
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();
```

When we call the `show()`, it removes the `display:none`. Similarly `hide()` adds `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. You can use firebug and check the styles applied.

**Note:** You will get the same functionality if you remove the `li{display:none}` from CSS.

Comment: I have updated my question please check :). Because i want SPAN inside LI not outside when JS run.

Comment: Nothing works can you create an example. For better understanding :)

Comment: can you create a working example :) because is not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This inline style is being applied and overrides due to CSS specificity:

`display: list-item;`

One way to increase specificity is to use:

```
.ticker li {
    display:none !important;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Just debug the code and  check the style you applied.

This issue is due to the following javascript line in your code

```
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();
```

add this line

```
ticker.children(':first').show();
```